# Web3 handling of contract events

Tags: web3js, truffle, events, truffle-contract

It seems that there is an issue with handling of contract events and I am not sure if it is at the EVM level or just web3js.

I have 2 contracts "SomeCoin" and "SomeConcert". Both contracts emit "Transfer" event when there is a transfer of item from one address to another. For "SomeCoin" the object of transfer is a coin/token, for "SomeConcert" the object of transfer is concert tickets (that is priced in "SomeCoins").

When I called "SomeConcert" method to purchase tickets, the logic will transfer some "SomeCoins" from my address to the "SomeConcert" address. All is well and good except for the event handling. I saw 2 events emitted "Buy" event emitted from "SomeConcert" contract and "Transfer" event from "SomeCoin" contract. If I renamed the "Transfer" event in "SomeCoin" contract to "TransferCoin" then I will only see the "Buy" event.

So, apparently either web3 or the underlying layer confuses the events emitted by inner layer contract with the outer layer contract. At least this is the conclusion I have come to.

Is this a web3js bug? Is there anything I missed out in the event handling that might have prevented the confusion. The code I have for event handling is rather standard

`...
      return someConcertInstance.buyTickets(3, {from: customer1});
    }).then(function(receipt) {
      assert.equal(receipt.logs.length, 1, "should have received 1 events for buy-ticket)");
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._numberOfTickets, 3, "Number of tix bought must be 3");`

The test case failed on the first assert and I found out 2 events are emitted (transfer and buy).

Comment: It's expected that the transaction receipt contains two log entries, because two events were logged in that transaction. It's unexpected that you see only one log entry if you rename one of the events... perhaps it's a mismatch between the contract code and the ABI you're using?

Comment: I checked and indeed that's the behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confirming. Did you find a mismatch between the contract code and the ABI?

Comment: The ABI and contract are consistent. I used Truffle v4.1.5 and I cleared out everything in the "build" folder, restarted my testrpc, did a "Truffle compile --all" and "Truffle migrate --reset" though Truffle test is supposed to do cleanroom deployment. But the result remains - I will see the inner contract events if I have the same event signature at the outer contract. It seems to me there is some logic on how events are bubbled up the chain and probably they used the event name to filter. 
I wonder if this has to do with web3 or something more fundamental.

Comment: As I said, I believe you should see all logs that were generated by your transaction. The fact that one of the events seems to disappear based on the name of the event strikes me as a bug in web3.js... my best theory is that web3.js doesn't actually give you all the logs but rather just the ones matching a signature in the ABI. This may be by design, but I don't like that design. :-)

Comment: Which version of web3.js are you using? Or is this truffle?

Comment: yeah, it is either by design (which is a rather strange one) or a bug.
My truffle is 4.1.5 (latest), the web3 version shown in truffle console when I run web3.version is 0.20.6.

Comment: If this is indeed truffle, then it looks like the design is what I hypothesized: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/blob/develop/contract.js#L44. I would recommend filing an issue. I personally avoid truffle.

Comment: If you want to process only the events that came from a particular contract, it looks like they do expose an `address` field, so you can just filter on that.

Comment: Sorry, just saw an edit to one of your older comments. It looks like this is indeed truffle, so that's the issue.

Comment: does Truffle has their own web3js? Let me try to deploy the contracts on geth and see if I get the same behaviour

Comment: I believe they use web3.js underneath, but they certainly have their own contract object. (See https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract.) I believe web3.js 1.0.0-beta _may_ filter log messages similarly, and I believe web3.js 0.2x.x doesn't attempt to parse the log messages at all (and thus will leave them intact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted out in the comments above, moving to an answer for future readers.

The code in the question is using `truffle`. When sending a transaction in truffle, the result you get back has a `logs` field, which is assembled via this code: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/blob/develop/contract.js#L44.

That code discards logs with topics that don't match a known event signature in the ABI of the contract you're calling. I consider that behavior to be a design bug.